# JavaFX - HTMLElements are null when changing pages

Tags: java, webview, javafx

When a user clicks on a link, I want to change the page and then load the relevant info.

However, the `HTMLElement` is always `null`.

The following is the code:

**WebViewPanel.java**

```
//to be used in JFX Thread
public void loadURLFX(final String url) {
    if (Misc.stringHasContent(url)) {

        String tmp = toURL(url);

        if (tmp == null) {
            tmp = toURL("http://" + url);
        }

        boolean invalidURL = false;
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL(tmp);
            stream = urlObj.openStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            invalidURL = true;
        } finally {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            stream = null;
        }

        if (!invalidURL) {
            engine.load(tmp);
        } else {
            //https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=searchTerm
            engine.load("https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=" + url);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public void load(){
    if(Platform.isFxApplicationThread()){
        webViewPanel.loadURLFX(App.class.getResource("/hello.html").toExternalForm());
        HTMLElement element = (HTMLElement) WebMisc.getHTMLElement(webViewPanel.getWebEngine(), "menu");
    }
}
```

*`element` is always null*. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: What is `menu` in your `hello.html` ?

Comment: Are you using getElementById()? Wait the page for being fully loaded. See the javadoc of WebEngine.